# Использование двух обработчиков для отправки

Tags: jquery, ajax

Возможно ли в `ajax` запросе, предоставленном ниже, применить два обработчика формы, помимо `mail.php`?

```js
  $("#form").submit(function() {
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../mail.php",
      data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      alert("Thank you, your message was sent.");
      setTimeout(function() {
        th.trigger("reset");
      }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, сделать два запроса на разные урлы?

Comment: Да, всё верно предположили

Comment: ну дак допишите второй запрос. в чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте Promise.all, чтобы отправить два запроса и выполнить колбэк, когда оба будут успешны.

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var th = $(this);

    Promise.all([
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../mail.php",
        data: th.serialize()
      }), 
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../mail2.php",
        data: th.serialize()
      })
    ])
    .then(function(results) {
      console.log(results);
      alert("Thank you, your message was sent.");
      setTimeout(function() {
        th.trigger("reset");
      }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```